# AHK-Studio stuck at downloading

Tags: ide, autohotkey

Downloaded the AHK-StudioMaster.zip from Github

AHK-Studio directory-- https://ibb.co/r4QK2x2

Stuck at this download screen -- https://ibb.co/M5nLptC

using Win 7 64bit.

AHK version 1.1.33.09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this only happens with Windows 7 fresh installs (*or without security updates*).

Here's how to fix:

1. Install [2019 security updates](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4474419)
2. Some other updates provided by [ProtonVPN](https://protonvpn.com/) (while installing it will automatically install required updates)
3. [These 5 updates](https://www.techwhitesolution.com/2021/12/how-to-manually-update-windows-7.html) ***in order***.

After installing these three, AHK-Studio can now access internet connection and complete downloading process.

[Mission accomplished!](https://ibb.co/mt6PJDB)

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the main AutoHotkey executable (or `AHK-Studio.exe` if it's compiled) through your firewall so that it can update and download its dependencies. It does this on every startup, but you can disable it by creating an empty file called `NoUpdate.txt` in AHK-Studio's directory (where `AHK-Studio.ahk` is located)—but you'll probably want to let it update at least once after a fresh install, or else the themes and languages won't be set correctly and you might not be able to see/read it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link: `https://github.com/maestrith/AHK-Studio/archive/master.zip`

This link works for me, the other one may be down atm

Comment: Their screenshots show they've already downloaded and run it, it's hanging on the auto-update.